# ¿Cómo crear un script SQL para insertar valores?

Tags: mysql, batch

Estoy intentando insertar los valores de esta manera:

```
INSERT INTO `paises`.`moneda` (`mon_id`, `moneda`, `abr`, `tipoCambio`, `singPlur`, `caracter`,`mn` ,`img16`, `img24`, `img32`, `status`)
VALUES (1, PESO MEXICANO, MXN, 18.7000, PESO:PESOS, $, 1,?,?,?,1);
```

Quiero ponerlos en un script `.sql` y posteriormente ejecutarlo con un archivo `.bat`

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Insertando Datos...
"C:\Users\Winchester\Desktop\mysql.exe" -u root --password=javac -P 3306 < "C:\Users\Winchester\Desktop\insertar-monedas.sql"
ECHO Completado
pause
```

Pero me sale el error de

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'MEXICANO, MXN, 18.7000, PESO:PESOS, $,
>   1,?,?,?,1)' at line 2

Comment: ¿Y cual es tu problema?

Comment: intentastes que e. .batch te genere el archivo sql que necesites, luego cargas el archivo con el comando mysql -u root -p mibasededatos < miarchivo.sql

Comment: acabo de editarlo para incluir mas detalles, solo que no tenia idea de como hacer nada de ello (crear batch o sql), me sigue dando error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltaban las comillas en la linea de `VALUES`

```
INSERT INTO `paises`.`moneda` (`mon_id`, `moneda`, `abr`, `tipoCambio`, `singPlur`, `caracter`,`mn` ,`img16`, `img24`, `img32`, `status`)
VALUES (1,"PESO MEXICANO","MXN",18.7000,"PESO:PESOS","$", 1,"?","?","?",1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Saludos,

Yo creo el `.bat` de la siguiente manera:

```
sqlcmd  -U adminsql01 -P passadmin -S SQLSERVER -i D:\SQLscripts\DesbloqueoUsuarios.sql -o D:\SQLscripts\DesbloqueoUsuariosSQLOutput.txt
```

y el SQL simplemente lo guardo como `DesbloqueoUsuarios.sql`

ya luego con una terea de windows lo ejecuto diariamente.
Pues esa es la idea, ya de ahi lo adaptas tu.